# Multi-select from mouse-only: functional in FF and IE, nothing happens in Chrome

Tags: html, select, google-chrome

I have a question, regarding how the select text box is supposed to perform multiselect. Basically, for the below HTML, I'd like to know why Chrome won't allow me to select **using only the mouse**. There are no problems, using click + Ctrl/Shift, but when I try to select by left-click + dragging the mouse over items in the list, nothing happens. Both FF and IE support this kind of selection.

What I would like to know, is if I could get around the problem without using ridiculous amounts of JavaScript to reinvent selection; secondly, why does this happen.

A sample select:

```
<select id="ListBoxFound" multiple="multiple" name="ListBoxFound">
  <option value="756">Teacher Assistants </option>
  <option value="744">Teachers and Instructors, All Other </option>
  <option value="284">Team Assemblers </option>
  <option value="775">Technical Directors/Managers </option>
  <option value="794">Technical Writers </option>
  <option value="227">Telecommunications Equipment Installers and Repairers, Except Line Installers </option>
  <option value="259">Telecommunications Line Installers and Repairers </option>
  <option value="478">Telecommunications Specialists </option>
  <option value="1036">Telemarketers </option>
  <option value="1041">Telephone Operators </option>
  <option value="1052">Tellers </option>
  <option value="171">Terrazzo Workers and Finishers </option>
  <option value="725">Textile Bleaching and Dyeing Machine Operators and Tenders </option>
  <option value="726">Textile Cutting Machine Setters, Operators, and Tenders </option>
  <option value="1075">Textile Knitting and Weaving Machine Setters, Operators, and Tenders </option>
  <option value="333">Textile Winding, Twisting, and Drawing Out Machine Setters, Operators, and Tenders </option>
  <option value="337">Textile, Apparel, and Furnishings Workers, All Other </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simulating this behavior by attaching event handlers to mouseUp, mouseDown and mouseOver events. I use mouseUp and mouseDown to control whether it's selecting or not, and the actual selection happens in mouseOver.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var sele = false;
var last = null;
$("select#ListBoxFound>option").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).attr('selected', sele);
    sele = false;
}).mousedown(function(){
  $(this).attr('selected', sele);
    last = $(this);
    sele = true;
}).mouseover(function() { 
    if (sele) {
        var oldv =  $(this).attr('selected');
        if(oldv == last.attr('selected')) {
            last.attr('selected', !oldv);
        }
        $(this).attr('selected', !oldv);
        last = $(this);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

The purpose of complicating the function with `last` and `oldv` is that onMouseOver only fires once if you're changing the direction of selection; for instance, if you start selecting downwards, and then go up, the last option the mouse has touched will remain selected, and every option above it will deselect.